# ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in a Location in Apache

Tags: apache, proxy, configuration, nuxt.js, reverse-proxy

I've been given something which I suspect never worked as intended, and I have been mucking about with it with no success.  I am guessing that this is *really simple* though, since it would seem a normal thing to want.

I have a location defined in vhost.conf, and this is an approximation:

```
<Location /myplace>
    ProxyPass http://myContainer:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://myContainer:8080
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyErrorOverride off 
</Location>
```

I try to load /myplace in a browser, and the container responds, providing content, for example: /mystuff.html

The Apache server is trying to serve up /mystuff.html directly and getting a 404

I want it to prepend the /myplace path so it serves /myplace/mystuff.html and gets the 200 it should.

If I do this by hand, the files are served up with a 200.  The container is providing them.

The container is a Nuxt.js server, if that's of any help.

I have tried many permutations of this, adding /mystuff to the end of the ProxyPass and the ProxyPassReverse, taking it out of the Location and doing both or either as a simple directive.

Nothing seems to have changed this behavior.